# How to sort my beautiful soup code so that it downloads what it scrapes either reverse alphabetically or specific letter

Tags: python, sorting, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to write code that scrapes video game ROMS off archive.org, it currently downloads all files from top to bottom which is already in alphabetical order. My computer can not download all of the files in one go, so I would like to know how I could either have it sort from reverse alphabetical order or be able to tell the code to start at a particular letter.

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

DOMAIN = 'https://archive.org/'
URL = 'https://archive.org/download/nointroNintendoDSDecrypted_2020Mar08/'
FILETYPE = '%28USA%29.7z'

def get_soup(url):
    return bs(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

for link in get_soup(URL).find_all('a'):
    file_link = link.get('href')
    if FILETYPE in file_link:
        print(file_link)
        with open(link.text, 'wb') as file:
           response = requests.get(URL + file_link)
           file.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an array of all the files - like this `["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"]`, just an example.

We can then run over them and start at a certain letter like so

```
def startAt(letter, array):
  for a in ar:
    if a.startswith(letter):
        # Download
```

This would work like so, with the example array

```
startAt("a", ar) # Download 4 times
startAt("b", ar) # Download 2 times
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, for this to work, I would need to know every file name on the website for this to work? At the current moment the code just reads the website and downloads all files that have the same format type.